# Create Zip files in Classic ASP using DotNetZip or SharpZipLib

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp-classic, dotnetzip

In ASP.Net two of the possible ways to make the zip files are

[Sharp Zip Library](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/)

[Dot Net Zip Library](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)

How can i use any of these in Classic ASP to make the zip files ? And which one will be better ?

Comment: @Steven. Thanks :-(( I worked in ASP.Net 4.0 but somehow i have to do some work on this application.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use any of those libraries in classic asp. One way would be to try to register them as COM components using the [regasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(VS.71).aspx) utility, although I am not sure whether those assemblies are marked with the [COMVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx) attribute.

Comment: incorrect.  You can use DotNetZip in classic ASP.  DotNetZip is decorated with ComVisible, and if you install DotNetZip with the MSI file, then the DLL is registered with regasm automatically.  It can then be used from any COM environment, including ASP (VBScript or Javascript or any other ASP language).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a [COM wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301750.aspx) for the .NET library of choice.

You will then be able to reference the wrapper in classic ASP and use it.

Comment: Instead of building the .Net assembly for COM Components i found another solution for classic ASP.

http://www.xstandard.com/en/documentation/xzip/

Comment: @Umar Siddique - you specifically asked about using those .NET libaries in classic ASP... Of course you can use existing COM libraries :)

Comment: X-Standard zip component works for me. Now the only thing is to register is on server. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, you do not need to create a COM wrapper for DotNetZip.  DotNetZip is already COM ready, and can be used from within classic ASP to read or write zip files.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to some perception, it's easy to use DotNetZip from COM environments, including ASP.

DotNetZip includes examples that show creating zip files from VBScript and Javascript. 
You can easily adapt this code  to use it from ASP classic.

There is also an example in the source code for reading a ZIP file from within an ASP classic page.  It looks like this:

```
<%@ LANGUAGE = VBScript %>
<%  Option Explicit %>
<%

' -------------------------------------------------------
' ASP DotNetZip Example
' -------------------------------------------------------
' This example ASP page uses DotNetZip (Ionic.Zip.dll) via COM
' interop.  The page opens a zip file, then allows the user
' to download any individual file within the zip file. 
' 
'' To get this to work, you must be sure to register DotNetZip for COM
'' interop (regasm).  Also you need to be sure that IIS/ASP has the correct
'' permissions to instantiate the ZipFile object.  In my experience I Was
'' able to do this by copying Ionic.Zip.dll to the
'' c:\windows\system32\inetsrv directory, then calling "regasm /codebbase
'' Ionic.Zip.dll" from within that directory.

'' This example assumes that the ASP page is deployed into a directory,
'' that contains a subdirectory called "fodder".  Fodder must be readable,
'' and should contain one or more zip files.  This page allows the user to
'' select a zip file, then select a file within the zip file, and download
'' that file.
''

If Request.Form("Submit") = "Download" Then 
   dim pathForZipFile, fileToDownload
   pathForZipFile= Request.Form("zipFile")
   if pathForZipFile <> "" Then
     fileToDownload = Request.Form("fileToDownload")
     Response.Clear
     Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & fileToDownload  
     Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"  

     pathForZipFile = Server.MapPath("fodder\" & pathForZipFile)

     dim zip, ms
     set zip = Server.CreateObject("Ionic.Zip.ZipFile")
     zip.Initialize(pathForZipFile)

     set ms = Server.CreateObject("System.IO.MemoryStream")

     dim selectedEntry, entry
     For Each entry in zip
         If entry.FileName = fileToDownload  Then 
           set selectedEntry = entry 
         End If 
     Next

     selectedEntry.Extract_3(ms)
     zip.Dispose

     dim fred
     fred = ms.ToArray

     Response.BinaryWrite(fred)
     ms.Dispose
   End If

Else

%>

<html>
   <HEAD>
<TITLE>Simple DotNetZip Example</TITLE>
<style>
BODY { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 10pt;}
TD {  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  font-size: 8pt;}
TH {  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  font-size: 10pt;}
H2 { font-size: 16pt; font-weight: bold; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:Navy;}
H1 { font-size: 20pt; font-weight: bold; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:Blue;}
</style>


   <script language="Javascript">

    function Download(file, zipFile)
    {
        document.form1.fileToDownload.value = file;
        document.form1.zipFile.value = zipFile;
        document.form1.submit();
    }

   </script>



   <script RUNAT=Server language="VBScript">

   '-------------------------------------
   ' This reads the given zip file. 
   '-------------------------------------
   Sub DisplayContentsOfZip
    dim pathForZipFile
    pathForZipFile= Request.Form("selectedZip")
    if pathForZipFile <> "" Then
        pathForZipFile = Server.MapPath("fodder\" & pathForZipFile)

        dim zip
        set zip = Server.CreateObject("Ionic.Zip.ZipFile")
        zip.Initialize(pathForZipFile)

        response.write "<table border=1><tr><th>Name</th><th>last modified</th></tr>"

        dim entry, fN
        For Each entry in zip
         If Right(entry.FileName,1) <> "/" Then 
             Response.Write "<tr><TD><input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Download' onClick=" & chr(34) & "Download('" & _
             entry.FileName & "', '" & Request.Form("selectedZip")  & "');" & chr(34) & " ></TD><td>" & _
             entry.FileName & "</td><td>" & entry.LastModified & "</td></tr>"
         End If
        Next
        response.write "</table>"
        zip.Dispose()
    End If
   End Sub


   '-------------------------------------
   ' This function builds and returns the 
   ' option list for the form. eg:
   '    <OPTION value="file1.zip">file1.zip</OPTION>
   '    <OPTION value="file2.zip">file2.zip</OPTION>
   '    <OPTION value="file3.zip">file3.zip</OPTION>
   '-------------------------------------
   Function FileList()
     Dim fso, folder, ext, item, result
     result = ""
     Set fso= Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(Server.MapPath("fodder"))
     For Each item In folder.Files
         ext = Right(item.Name,4)
         If (ext = ".zip") Then
           result = result & "<OPTION value='" & item.Name & "'>" & item.Name & "</OPTION>"
         End If
     Next 
     Set fso = Nothing
     Set folder = Nothing
     FileList = result
   End Function

   </script>

   </HEAD>

<body>
<h1>ASP DotNetZip</h1>

<p> This page shows how to use <a
href="http://DotNetZip.codeplex.com">DotNetZip</a> from an ASP (Classic)
page.  This page reads zip files and allows the browser to download
items from the zip files.  </p>

<form METHOD="POST" id='form1' name='form1'>

   <TABLE style="border:1; cellspacing:1; cellpadding:1;">
<TR> <TD>Select a Zip file:</TD>
  <TD><SELECT id='select1' name='selectedZip'>
    <%= fileList %>
    </SELECT>
  </TD>
</TR>
<TR> <TD/><TD><input type='submit' name="Submit" Value="Read Zip"/></TD> </TR>
   </TABLE>

   <input type="hidden" name="fileToDownload" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="zipFile" value="">

<%
DisplayContentsOfZip
%>

</form>

</body>
</html>

<%
End If
%>
```

To see the latest version of this example, go to http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets and click on "Browse", then expand the directory called "Examples".